# Is the following two versions mean the same thing?

Tags: servlets, jetty

We are pleased to announce the immediate availability of Jetty
7.5.3.v20111011 and Jetty 8.0.3.v20111011.

why 7.5.3 and 8.0.3 release at the same day? Is this the same jetty version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 versions are not the same. They likely released two different releases of v7 and v8  product versions to patch a software bug or security vulnerability which existed in both versions.

Comment: why they keep two major versions?

Comment: Because there may be many people still using the older major version.

Comment: Usually when this happens, new feature development would only be occurring on the newer version (v8 in this case) however the older v7 would continue to be updated with important bug fixes and security fixes for as long as the version is supported. This allows customers to continue to receive updates for the older version before they are ready to upgrade to the new version.